# Question Limit Clarification

Tags: support

I asked my first question the other day and it got negative votes so I ended up deleting it by asking moderators to do so since it had an answer on it but it was a bad question regardless so it didn't need to stay.

I ended up asking another question and was originally asked to split it into two questions. I was able to edit that question into just one but I've been receiving the below message for a few days even though my bad question has been deleted.

Is there a way to get a moderator override on this below restriction since that bad question has been removed? Otherwise, I suppose I could create another account, ask the question, and ask for the accounts to be merged later once some time has passed?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system doesn't forget your deleted questions, and that is by design.  The idea is to prevent new users from creating too much low-quality content.  Deleted questions count toward that.

I think you can wait another day before asking a new question.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish There's a "deleted recent questions" link in the [questions tab in your profile](http://politics.stackexchange.com/users/7229/1fish-2fish-redfish-bluefish?tab=questions). It should lead you to [this question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/the-pros-and-cons-of-democratic-socialism-in-america-today).

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish Did you click the "deleted recent questions" link?

Comment: @Yannis That's exactly what I was NOT doing actually. This completes the answer to my question now that you point that out!!